# Truncate hostname portion from PROMPT

Tags: zsh

I have some instances that are part of a cloud environment. Their name is suffixed with an UUID, like:

```
<name-of-host>-411a7a0e-b409-46a0-bf8f-546ffc50ee2b
```

I don't want to hide it, since it helps me to know in which machine I'm in, so I'd like to see only the first 20 characters.

My default prompt is like:

```
PROMPT="[%n@%m %1~]%(#.#.$) "
```

So, my first attempt was:

```
PROMPT="[%n@%20>...>%m %1~]%(#.#.$) "
```

However, this doesn't work, as it shows like this:

```
user@name-of-host...<command prompt is right here>
```

Then I tried like this:

```
PROMPT="[%n@%{%20>...>%m%} %1~]%(#.#.$) "
```

It displays the prompt correctly, but when I try something like bck-i-search (<kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>), the portion inside the `%{...%}` is overwritten.

The ZSH docs explain why:

> ```
> %{...%}
> Include a string as a literal escape sequence.  The
>   string within the braces should not change the cur-
>   sor position.  Brace pairs can nest.
> ```

Is there any other way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can end truncations - as in "truncate only up to here" - with `%>>` or `%<<`:

```sh
PROMPT="[%n%20>...>%m%>> %1~]%(#.#.$) "
```

Here is the relevant part from the [ZSH manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts):

> The part of the prompt string to be truncated runs to the end of the string, or to the end of the next enclosing group of the **`` `%(' ``** construct, or to the next  truncation  encountered  at  the  same grouping level (i.e. truncations inside a **`` `%(' ``** are separate), which ever comes first.  In particular, a truncation with argument zero (e.g., **`` `%<<' ``**) marks the end of the range of the string to be truncated while turning off truncation from there on. For example, the prompt **`` `%10<...<%~%<<%#  ' ``** will  print  a  truncated representation of the current directory, followed by a **`` `%' ``** or **`` `#' ``**, followed by a space.  Without the **`` `%<<' ``**, those two characters would be included in the string to be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the hostname doesn't change from command to command, you could just include it into PROMPT as a literal string instead of using `%m`.

That is, something like

```
short_hostname="$(hostname|sed -e 's/-.*//')"
PROMPT="[%n@${short_hostname} %1~]%(#.#.$) "
```